# Race condition with setpgid

Tags: c, linux, posix, pid, fork

While working on a program for my OS class, I discovered an interesting case involving a what appears to be a race condition involving `setpgid`.

Compile each program below separately. After executing `./test 3` (or any number > 2), `ps jx` will show that all of the `infy` processes have been placed in the same group. `./test 2` will present an error that `setpgid` has failed attempting to move the last process. Uncommenting the "fix me" line will cause `./test 2` to work as expected.

Can anyone offer an explanation or solution?

```
// test.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* args[] = {
  "./infy",
  NULL
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [num]\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  int num = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  if (num < 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of processes\n");
    return 1;
  }

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid > 0)
  {
    int s;
    waitpid(pid, &s, 0);
    fprintf(stderr, "Children done\n");
  }
  else
  {
    pid_t pgid = -1;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
      pid_t pid2 = fork();
      if (pid2 > 0)
      {
        if (pgid == -1)
        {
          pgid = pid2;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (setpgid(0, pgid == -1 ? 0 : pgid) != 0)
        {
          perror("setpgid failed in non-last process");
        }
        execve(args[0], args, NULL);
        perror("exec failed");
        exit(1);
      }
    }

    // uncomment me to fix
    //fprintf(stderr, "pgid %d\n", pgid);
    if (setpgid(0, pgid) != 0)
    {
      perror("setpgid failed in last process");
    }
    execve(args[0], args, NULL);
    perror("exec failed");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Where "infy" is a separate program:

```
// infy.c
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  while (1)
  {
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, finally.  When `setpgid` failed, `errno` was set to `EPERM`.  One of the possible errors on the man page for `EPERM` is:

> The value of the pgid argument is valid but does not match the process ID of the process indicated by the pid argument and there is no process with a process group ID that matches the value of the pgid argument in the same session as the calling process.

The race condition in this case is whether the child process can set its pgid before the parent does.  If the child wins the race, all is well.  If the parent wins the race, the process group it is attempting to set doesn't exist yet, and `setpgid` fails.

The solution is for the parent process to set the child's group id immediately after the first fork, by calling `setpgid(pid2, pid2)` in the `if (pgid == -1)` block.

Also relevant, from the man page:

> To provide tighter security, setpgid() only allows the calling process to join a process group already in use inside its session or create a new process group whose process group ID was equal to its process ID.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question appears to be given in the man page for setpgid(2):

```
ERRORS
       EACCES An attempt was made to change the process group ID of
              one of the children of the calling process and the child
              had  already  performed an execve(2) (setpgid(),
              setpgrp()).
```

It's a race condition. If your original parent process, the one that ends up running the setpgid() call below your comment, manages to execute it before its child process execve()s the other executable, it will succeed. If the child process manages to execve() before the parent gets to setpgid(), the parent setpgid()'s will fail.

The presence of the absence of your fprintf() call ends up changing the execution profile of the parent process, and changing it enough so that it ends up affecting the likelyhood of the parent process winning or losing the race.

I find it quite interesting that the additional fprintf() call appears to actually make your parent process *win the race*! But it is what it is.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case.  The child process(es) changes its own pgid.  The parent process changes its own pgid.  The parent never attempts to change the pgid of any child.  Also, you can replace fprintf() with a call to sleep(), and it still causes the issue to be fixed.  There is *no way* the parent could be winning the race after it has slept for several seconds!

Answer (score 1):

Sam is right. I did a test, and found that even if the child doesn't call `setpgid()`, as long as it doesn't `execvp` the parent's call to `setpgid()` succeeds. Here is the demo code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    char* argv[3];
    argv[0] = strdup("sleep");
    argv[1] = strdup("10");
    argv[2] = NULL;

    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    cout << "execvp failed: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    exit(0);
  }

  sleep(5);

  int result = setpgid(pid, pid);
  cout << "setpgid return value: " << result << endl;
  if(result == -1) {
    cout << "setpgid failed: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    cout << "Errno: " << errno << endl;
    if(errno == EACCES) {
      cout << "yellow" << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If the sleep call is placed as is, the parents call to `setpgid()` goes through before the child does anything and succeeds. If the sleep call is moved to the alternative placement, then `execvp()` goes through first and the parents call fails with errno 13, and prints "yellow".